# Слова «прекрасно понимая» в предложении верно обособлены?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Мы работаем в одном направлении и намерены развивать сотрудничество прекрасно понимая, что смешанные единоборства сейчас на волне популярности.

Answer (score 1):

Вот чем интересно это предложение? Пр правилам пунктуации мы должны написать:

**Мы работаем в одном направлении и намерены развивать сотрудничество, прекрасно понимая, что смешанные единоборства сейчас на волне популярности.**

В записи текст понятен, но вот **в устной речи он читается как-то не так, причем не сразу сообразишь, в чём дело.**

А попробуем изменить структуру предложения, **добавив еще одно наречие**:

**Мы работаем в одном направлении и намерены развивать сотрудничество и дАльше, прекрасно понимая, что смешанные единоборства сейчас на волне популЯрности.**

Вот теперь всё читается нормально, деепричастный оборот больше  "не хочется" присоединить к первой части предложения, так как эта позиция занята наречием.

**Такое вот равновесие частей предложения**, которое важно, но которое мы обычно соблюдаем интуитивно.

Comment: Читается нормально, звучит красиво, а смысл? Вы уверены, что они развивали сотрудничество до этого момента?

Comment: Может они только сейчас объявили о своем намерении его развивать.

Comment: Дело не в конкретном слове, а в том, что в эту позицию надо поставить дополнительный (какой-нибудь) член предложения, чтобы оборот "не цеплялся" за  глагольное сочетание. В предложении нет равновесия частей.

Comment: С этим полностью согласен :)

Comment: Спасибо, я очень ценю вашу объективность и умение слышать собеседника. Редкое и очень достойное качество.

Answer (score 0):

Деепричастный оборот "прекрасно понимая, что смешанные единоборства сейчас на волне популярности" должен быть обособлен.

**Мы работаем в одном направлении и намерены развивать сотрудничество, прекрасно понимая, что смешанные единоборства сейчас на волне популярности.**

Comment: а если его изъять, получится по смыслу черт те что...

Comment: Если изъять деепричастный оборот, получится вполне осмысленная фраза: "Мы работаем в одном направлении и намерены развивать сотрудничество"

Comment: Похоже, Вы неверно определили границы оборота.

Comment: да, я туда и «что...» отнесла...

Comment: Тогда чем Вам не нравится то, что получится, если оборот изъять?

Comment: Вы же сами написали, что я неверно определила оборот.....«Мы работаем в одном направлении и намерены развивать сотрудничество, что смешанные единоборства сейчас на волне популярности».

Comment: Теперь понял...

Comment: я думала, что изымание деепричастного оборота из ВСЕГО предложения....